# Make Mac OS X acknowledge Speech Recognition keyword?

Tags: macos, speech-recognition

Can I make Mac OS X "ping" when it recognizes the Speech Recognition keyword?

It pings when it recognizes a phrase, but that's a little different.

My speech recognition is working fine without a keyword, but fails 
when I use a keyword, even if it's a short keyword like "Bob" or 
"Hal".

If I can at least know when it's accepted the keyword, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Have other people tried to use Speech Recognition on your machine and failed? The recognizer can, sometimes, have issues with certain accents. Use the OS X text-to-speech system to read out what you want to say (use Alex or one of the other normal-speech voices [i.e. not Zarvox]) and try to match its pronunciation exactly.